# How to start a Pinch Zoom Gesture from previous scale?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use a Pinch Gesture Recognizer to scale a UITextView up and down, however it always starts at a scale of 1.0.
I've tried to implement these answers: 
[iOS Pinch Zoom Start from Previous Scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53963768/ios-pinch-zoom-start-from-previous-scale) 
[UIPinchGestureRecognizer. Make zoom in location of fingers, not only center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245127/uipinchgesturerecognizer-make-zoom-in-location-of-fingers-not-only-center) 
[Pinch gesture scale resetting to 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280004/pinch-gesture-scale-resetting-to-1)

but i must be doing something wrong, because it still resets to a scale of 1.0 each time. Here's my code:

```
@objc func pinchRecognized(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

var lastScale:CGFloat = 1.0

    if let view = recognizer.view as? UITextView {

        if (recognizer.state == .began) {
            lastScale = 1.0
        }

        let scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - recognizer.scale)

        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        view.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40 * scale)

        lastScale = recognizer.scale

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `lastScale` will always be `1` because this method is deleted out of memory once it is used, until it is called again. Therefore, `lastScale` will always reset to 1. On top of that, you have `recognizer.state == began` and setting `lastScale = 1` which means that everytime a new touch is called, `lastscale = 1`.

What you should be doing is creating a global variable, not local variable, and adjusting that scale. This will allow it to not reset back to 1 everytime. Also, don’t ever reset `lastScale` unless you press some reset function. Think about it - why would you want to reset your lastScale after it is set?

Answer (score 1):

In swift 5, you can just do this:

```
@objc func pinchHandler(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let view = sender.view else { return }
    view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale)
    sender.scale = 1
}
```